# Problem with static file middleware when publish web api net core on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have published a web api .net core to Azure. Everything works fine until i use static file middleware and store my website's images in my Content folder. It's okay when i run website locally, i can get images from Content folder with http://localhost/Content/Images/abc.jpg but when i try to publish my website to Azure again, i got Internal Server Error. How can i fix that error?

This is my Configure method in Startup file

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Client_URL"].ToString())
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
                RequestPath = "/Content"
            });
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the below option, if not try this and see if it helps.

I am assuming it might be the issue with folder permissions that are set. Can you try creating a new folder within the content directory and add a folder inside. Then try changing that particular folder permission settings by adding a group or usernames and allow full control, then try to publish the particular folder specifically to Azure and it should usually work.